# How to show two integers are relatively prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are positive integers. How do I show that $\frac{a}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}$ and $\frac{b}{\text{gcd}(a,b)}$ are relatively prime?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $c\mid \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $c\mid \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}$ with $c>1$.
Then $c\gcd(a,b)\mid a$ and $c\gcd(a,b)\mid b$, so $c\gcd(a,b)$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$ that is strictly greater than $\gcd(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

$a/\gcd$ removes all the common factors between $a,b$ from $a$, and the same with $b/\gcd$. I.e., there are no common factors between them, and hence, $\gcd(a/\gcd,b/\gcd)=1$.

Comment: thank you for such a clear explanation!

Comment: @LeiaHassan Sure!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Work with their prime factorizations: $a=\prod {p_i}^{s_i}$ and $b=\prod {q_i}^{t_i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $c\cdot \gcd(a,b)=\gcd(ca,cb)$ for $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Q}$, you have $1=\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{\gcd(a,b)}=\gcd\left(\frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)},\frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\right)$.